# Using a batch file to replace Javascript code?

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to do a JavaScript code find and replace using a batch file. Here is an Example:

Find: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mega.edu/Course/WebCTfooter/footer.js">Footer</script>`

Replace: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mega.edu/Course/WebCTfooter/footer_ungrad.js">Footer</script>`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to change the javascript text file? If so, you could use Notepad++ which is a free text editor software that will allow you to do a find and replace in a given directory. It should do what you want.

Comment: It would be easy if your machine had perl, python, or sed installed.  But I think some more details would be helpful - for example, why isn't search/replace in a text editor an option?

Comment: Good Question !! I can't do the search and replace in a text editor because I have about 25 queries that I have to run which are somewhat similar to the one above. Doing them at once is a big pain. Thus I am using the python script and batch to automate the find and replace process

Comment: What Batch file detractors had not seen yet is that any solution that use a Windows GUI application involve a manual work much more extensive than double-click the Batch file icon. Just a thought...

Comment: @Ahmed - you should vote up one or more of the solutions that sound good, and accept one that you think you'd use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can use python, I recommend using a python program instead of a batch file, perhaps something like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import shutil
import sys
import re

for path in sys.argv[1:]:
    print "processing " + path
    infile = open(path,'r')
    tmpfile = open(path+'.tmp','w')

    # make the replacements
    for line in infile:
        line = re.sub("/footer.js","/footer_ungrad.js",line)
        line = re.sub("/header.js","/header_ungrad.js",line)
        line = re.sub("/sample.js","/sample_ungrad.js",line)
        tmpfile.write(line)

    infile.close()
    tmpfile.close()

    # now move it back to the original file
    shutil.move(path+'.tmp',path)
```

Tested with python 2.4.

Comment: well I think I will go with the python script because it makes it easier to handle. Though I have found another use for the batch code. Anyways Thank you guys for helping me out.